flutter_quill incorrectly recording text attributes
Im not sure what the issue is but i think flutter_quill is not recording the information correctly.
this is what i see in the ui::

this is the content in the quill editor:
quill text::

{insert: this is normal text
this is header 1 text}

{insert:
, attributes: {header: 1}}

{insert: this is header 2 text}

{insert:
, attributes: {header: 2}}

{insert: this is header 1 text}

{insert:
, attributes: {header: 1}}


The issue is that in the UI it looks like this[font]:
is is normal text.        [normal font]
this is header 1 text.    [bigger font]


this is the code::
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart';

class QuillInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> column;
  final String value;
  final Function(String, dynamic) on_changed;
  final Function(Function(String)) onRegisterInsertCallback;

  QuillInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.column,
    required this.on_changed,
    required this.onRegisterInsertCallback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuillInput> createState() => _QuillInputState();
}

class _QuillInputState extends State<QuillInput> {
  late QuillController _controller;
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  bool _isInitialized = false;
  String _errorMessage = '';
  int _lastCursorPosition = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeController();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(QuillInput oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
      _updateControllerValue();
    }
  }

  void _initializeController() {
    try {
      _focusNode = FocusNode();
      _controller = QuillController(
        document: _parseDocument(widget.value),
        selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
      );
      _setupListeners();
      _isInitialized = true;
      _errorMessage = '';
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print("QuillInput - Error in _initializeController: $e");
      print("QuillInput - Stack trace: $stackTrace");
      _errorMessage = 'Error initializing editor: $e';
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _updateControllerValue() {
    final newDocument = _parseDocument(widget.value);
    final diff = _controller.document.toDelta().diff(newDocument.toDelta());
    if (diff.isNotEmpty) {
      _controller.compose(diff, TextSelection.collapsed(offset: _lastCursorPosition), ChangeSource.remote);
    }
  }

  Document _parseDocument(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return Document()..insert(0, '\n');
    }
    try {
      // print("QuillInput - Parsing value: $value");
      final documentData = jsonDecode(value);

      // Ensure the last element ends with a newline
      if (documentData.isNotEmpty && documentData.last['insert'] is String) {
        final lastInsert = documentData.last['insert'];
        if (!lastInsert.endsWith('\n')) {
          documentData.last['insert'] += '\n';
        }
      }

      return Document.fromJson(documentData);
    } catch (e) {
      print("QuillInput - Error parsing value as JSON: $e");
      // Handle both escaped and unescaped newlines
      value = value.replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
      return Document()..insert(0, value + '\n');
    }
  }

  void _setupListeners() {
    _controller.addListener(_updateCursorPosition);
    _focusNode.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
    widget.onRegisterInsertCallback(_insertTextAtCursor);
  }

  void _updateCursorPosition() {
    setState(() {
      _lastCursorPosition = _controller.selection.baseOffset;
    });
  }

  void _handleFocusChange() {
    if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      String sysId = widget.column['sys_id'];
      String formattedText = jsonEncode(_controller.document.toDelta().toJson());

      print("on_changed: $formattedText");
      widget.on_changed(sysId, formattedText);
    }
  }

  void _insertTextAtCursor(String text) {
    int insertPosition = _lastCursorPosition;
    if (_controller.selection.baseOffset >= 0) {
      insertPosition = _controller.selection.baseOffset;
    }

    _controller.replaceText(insertPosition, 0, text, null);

    int newPosition = insertPosition + text.length;
    _controller.updateSelection(
      TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newPosition),
      ChangeSource.local,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_errorMessage.isNotEmpty) {
      return Center(child: Text(_errorMessage));
    }
    if (!_isInitialized) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          QuillToolbar.simple(
            configurations: QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
              controller: _controller,
              sharedConfigurations: const QuillSharedConfigurations(
                locale: Locale('de'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: QuillEditor.basic(
                configurations: QuillEditorConfigurations(
                  controller: _controller,
                  autoFocus: false,
                  expands: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  scrollable: true,
                ),
                focusNode: _focusNode,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.removeListener(_updateCursorPosition);
    _focusNode.removeListener(_handleFocusChange);
    _focusNode.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


I didnt see any other stack overflow questions like mine.
any advise or tips are welcome
